# VR videos with VR UI - iOS Google VR SDK

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, google-vr

During video playback I'd like to overlay a set of controls the user can interact with. Is this possible with the components provided in Google's SDK?

Can I leverage OpenGL to work in conjunction with the video player Google provides, or do I need to create my own player that renders in an OpenGL view?

Comment: Yes, I also like to know about this... I also asked another question here. do you have the similar problem described here also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374652/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-i-info-button-and-place-some-video-controllers-ov