# is it possible to remove the (i) info button and place some video controllers over 360 video Google VR?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cardboard, google-vr

The title says it all! but to be more clear, please check this screenshot. This is a 360 video playback using the Google VR https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/ but I want to know if it is possible to remove this little (info) button? and instead overlay our own set of video controlers?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google allow you to create a custom GVRView which doesn't have the (i) icon - but it involves creating your own OpenGL code for viewing the video.

A hack working on v0.9.0 is to find an instance of QTMButton:

```js
let videoView = GVRVideoView(frame: self.view.bounds)

for subview in self.videoView.subviews {
    let className = String(subview.dynamicType)
    if className == "QTMButton" {
        subview.hidden = true
    }
}
```

It is a hack though so it might have unintended consequences and might not work in past or future versions.

Comment: Working in v1.0 but not in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have an answer to my own question. Alright, the (i) button cannot be removed. at leased not for now. check this answer

> Hi. The (i) is intentional and designed to let users and other
>   developers understand the feature. It links to a Google help center
>   article. We do not currently allow developers to disable it.

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/9#issuecomment-208993643

Answer (score 1):

```
GVRVideoView  *videoView = [[GVRVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

for (UIView *view in videoView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {
           if ([NSStringFromClass([view class])  isEqualToString:@"QTMButton"] ) {
               [view removeFromSuperview];
           }
        }
    }
```